# Predeploy command fails on dokku

Tags: python, dokku, python-poetry

My app.json looks like this

```
{
    "scripts": {
      "dokku": {
        "predeploy": "poetry run python manage.py collectstatic --noinput && poetry run python manage.py migrate"
      }
    }
}
```

And it gives this error

```
 !     Predeploy command declared: 'poetry run python manage.py collectstatic --noinput && poetry run python manage.py migrate'
remote: execution of 'poetry run python manage.py collectstatic --noinput && poetry run python manage.py migrate' failed!
       Creating virtualenv foxflash-9TtSrW0h-py3.6 in /app/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs
       Traceback (most recent call last):
         File "manage.py", line 9, in main
           from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
       ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
       The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
       Traceback (most recent call last):
         File "manage.py", line 20, in <module>
           main()
         File "manage.py", line 15, in main
           ) from exc
       ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

Not sure what to try out more to be honest.

Comment: when you call `poetry run ...`, poetry creates a new virtual environment if it can't find one. this new virtual env won't have any of your dependencies installed, like django. I don't know what dokku is, but in case you have your system python set up to run your django app directly, you can solve your issue by creating an environment variable calles `POETRY_VIRTUALENVS_CREATE` and set it to the value `false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing is that the virtualenv isn't activated. Which is weird since poetry should handle that.

However, for one, heroku doesn't support poetry.

You can use this buildpack:
https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/moneymeets/python-poetry-buildpack

According to the docs, a collectstatic should happen automatically during a deploy:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets#collectstatic-during-builds

And lastly: the poetry buildpack only creates a requirements.txt that is then installed with pip by the reqular heroku python buildpack.

Comment: Thanks @rolaand van laar, I'm not using heroku though, but dokku. Not using any buildpacks, everything is through a dockerfile I'll see if the buildpacks gives any clues though.

Comment: dokku behaves like heroku. http://dokku.viewdocs.io/dokku/deployment/application-deployment/

Comment: Worked brilliantly!